# React doesn't update component on change Array - Leaflet

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, maps, react-leaflet

I have an Array that has a boolean variable that decides which data is shown and which is not, those values ​​are changed from a checkbox in another component, what happens to me is that when updating the array, the map is not updated to the new data. If the message is not understood it is because I am using a translator.

```
import './Leaflet.css'
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer,} from 'react-leaflet'
import { Data } from '../../components/data/SidebarData'
import SubMapa from './SubMapa';
function Mapa() {
    const referencia = useRef();
    const center = [8.890498870150504, -80.1123046875]
    console.log(`hola`)
    return (
        <>
            <MapContainer center={center} zoom={8}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                {Data.map((items, index) => {

                    return <SubMapa items={items} key={index} />
                })}
            </MapContainer>
            
        </>
    ) 
}
export default Mapa;
```

Comment: A component will only rerender if there is a props or a state change, in your case it seems you are using fix data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `Data` as a prop instead of importing it, otherwise you component's state won't change and it won't re-render.

In your component:

```
const Mapa = ({ data }) => {
    const referencia = useRef();
    const center = [8.890498870150504, -80.1123046875]
    console.log(`hola`)
    return (
        <>
            <MapContainer center={center} zoom={8}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                {data.map((items, index) => {

                    return <SubMapa items={items} key={index} />
                })}
            </MapContainer>
            
        </>
    ) 
}

export default Mapa;
```

where you render your component:

```
<Mapa data={Data} />
```